# Triggering __call() in PHP even when method exists

Tags: php, magic-methods

The [PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php) says the following about the `__call()` magic method:

> __call() is triggered when invoking inaccessible methods in an object context.

Is there a way I can have `__call()` called even when a method exists, before the actual method is called? Or, is there some other hook I can implement or another way that would provide this functionality?

If it matters, this is for a `static function` (and I would actually prefer to use `__callStatic`).

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3241949/how-to-catch-any-method-call-on-object-in-php

Answer (score 12, accepted):

How about just make all your other methods protected, and proxy them through __callStatic?

```
namespace test\foo;

class A
{
    public static function __callStatic($method, $args)
    {
        echo __METHOD__ . "\n";

        return call_user_func_array(__CLASS__ . '::' . $method, $args);
    }

    protected static function foo()
    {
        echo __METHOD__ . "\n";
    }
}

A::foo();
```

Comment: I like this. I will keep this in mind for when I upgrade to PHP 5.3. Thanks.

Answer (score 22):

Why not just make all your methods protected and call them using __call():

```
 class bar{
    public function __call($method, $args){
        echo "calling $method";
        //do other stuff
        //possibly do method_exists check
        return call_user_func_array(array($this, $method), $args);
    }
    protected function foo($arg){
       return $arg;
    }
 }

$bar = new bar;
$bar->foo("baz"); //echo's 'calling foo' and returns 'baz'
```

Comment: need if(method_exists($this, $method)) {

Comment: I think that all protected methods would make a good chaos in structure. Better is to use `__call` with checking if method is public.