# How to intercept a method call in PHP?

Tags: php

Let's say I am using Doctrine ORM in my project (Doctrine is just an example, I am looking for a solution that would work with any class)

I want to intercept a call to `Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository::createQueryBuilder`

So, if somewhere in my code (or in any other library code) is issued a call to that method, I want to execute some code before the execution of the called method.

Any PHP version is fine for me, I don't need a minimal compatibility.

I took a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3241949/how-to-catch-any-method-call-on-object-in-php) but the solution requires that I have control on the instantiation of classes which is definitely not my case.

Any one has a clue how to achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: No built-in "magic" way of doing this. You either do it at a lower level, via a PHP module (C), _or_ wrap your classes in "Decorators" like described in that question.

Comment: Well, they are not *my classes* otherwise I would not be here :) But I still have hope :)

Comment: can you change EntityRepository class? do you have access to that

Comment: I also need this info. :)

Comment: @wonde If I would be able to change EntityRepository then I would just edit the method and don't need to *intercept* any calls

Comment: You can extend `Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository` and provide a custom implementation. Depending on who instantiates it and how it's instantiated you might need to extend some other classes too.

Comment: Extending is not an option, I have few dozens bundles, means few hundred classes using Doctrine, and all my changes will vanish within the next **composer update**