# Profiling *every* function call?

Tags: php

You may wonder why I would want to do this. I'm trying to debug PHP performance on an embedded system. Don't have access to any kind of tools on the device.

I was thinking if I could just do a simple `microseconds` calculation on every call, it would work.

Is there a way to do it? Essentially wrap all of my functions (not built in php).

This wouldn't be for production of course.

Comment: https://github.com/goaop/framework

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3241949/how-to-catch-any-method-call-on-object-in-php

Answer (score 0):

You can use `declare(ticks=1000);` to run an callback, like:

```
// you can use this:
declare(ticks=1);

// A function called on each tick event
function tick_handler()
{
    debug_backtrace();//get function name
    microtime();//get time
}
```

http://www.php.net/declare

you only have to get the right number e.g. `1000` for your tests cycles