# how to check if a concatenated method doesnt exist php

Tags: php

I am writing a function that calls another class and returns it so that I can execute my methods as `$this->myUser()->getUsername()`... now my question is:

Is there a way for me to intercept the `->getUsername()` from inside `myUser()` or intercept the fail to find?...

This is because I want to use another class that is `myUserExtended()` and I was wondering if I could route them both together inside `myUser()`. so that if `->getCity()` is not in `myUser()` it automaticaly goes on and uses another variable that containts `myUserExtended()`.

Probably is not possible, but it is worth asking.

```
private function myUser( $setMyUser = false ) {

        if( $setMyUser ) {
            $this->_myUser = $setMyUser;
        }

        if( empty( $this->$_myUser ) ) {
            $this->_myUser = UserQuery::create()->findPK( $this->variables('userID') );
        }

        return $this->_myUser;
    }
```

Comment: with the [magic method](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.call) `__call` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like this will help:

```
class MyUserClass {
  private $_myUser;
  public function myUser( $setMyUser = false ) {

        if( $setMyUser ) {
            $this->_myUser = $setMyUser;
        }

        if( empty( $this->$_myUser ) ) {
            $this->_myUser = UserQuery::create()->findPK( $this->variables('userID') );
        }

        return $this; //if you want to use method chaining, you have to return $this
    }
  public function __call($name, $arguments) {
    $ext = new myUserExtended();
    $ext->$name($arguments);
    return $ext;
  }
}

$myUser = new MyUserClass();

$myUser->myUser()->getCity("New York"); //this will call $ext->getCity(array("New York"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this may do the trick:

```
public function __call($name, $args)
{
    if (function_exists($this->_myUser->$name())) {
        return $this->_myUser->$name();
    }
    return $this->_myUserExtended->$name();
}
```

You'll obviously have to adjust it if you are using any arguments.

Comment: What do you do with the arguments ?

Comment: see http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.call - It has a few examples you can work with

Comment: I know, but I mean, if you call `$myObject->theMethod('arg1',21)`, if the method exists, will it call it first, or will it go to the `__call` ?

Comment: I think you are wrong : "__call() is triggered when invoking inaccessible methods in an object context.". That means you never get into your `if` condition. You should just check if the method does not exists.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1071894/triggering-call-in-php-even-when-method-exists

Comment: @Rijndael no it will not go to `__call` - if a method exists in a class, then that method will be used. If a method **doesn't** exist in that class, then `__call` will be used

Comment: @Ziarno yes but what if it is private or protected ? What I meant at the begining, is that you should do this : `return call_user_func_array(array($this, $name), $args);` to keep arguments

Answer (score 0):

`$this->myUser()->getUsername()` is equivalent to `$user = $this->myUser(); $user->getUsername()`. If you can add methods to whatever class the `$user` variable contains, then you can use the [__call()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.call) magic method and check if `->getCity()` exists. Or you could just add a method called `getCity()` that calls through to `myUserExtended()`.